# How do climate and location affect the Pine Processionary moth?

Tags: entomology, ecology, environment

I have statistics on the occurence of the Pine Processionary moth (*Thaumetopoea pityocampa*); we have the regions that are located in Algeria, infested area in percent, the defiliation degree (small, medium and high) and we have geographical location (longitude, lattitude).

The table is as follows:

[image]

Why is there a difference between infested areas, and is there a special pattern for the distribution of this insect? Is it known what the main drivers are for determining the distribution and abundance of this moth, and thereby why some areas are more infested than others?

Comment: I think you should merge this question with http://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/19103/classification-of-degree-of-infested-areas-by-pine-processionary-moth-on-regions, since they are very similar and clearly overlap.